# Intelligent way to generate tables with Liquid from a CSV file?

Tags: html, csv, jekyll, liquid

Okay, I'll try to make it short.

I got an XML [file from Musicbrainz](https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release/f8f0b71a-05c2-452e-baf7-771e77649a96?inc=aliases%2Bartist-credits%2Bdiscids%2Blabels%2Brecordings). Then I converted it to CSV and replaced the `.`'s with `_`'s to make it work with Liquid.

I put `music.csv` in `_data` and call it with:

`{% include music.html %}`

`_includes/music.html` looks (in part) like:

```
 <table border="1" style="width:100%">
<tr>
<td>Artist</td>
<td>Track title</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
{% if member.release_medium-list_medium_track-list_track_0_recording_artist-credit_name-credit_artist_name %}
    <td>{{ member.release_medium-list_medium_track-list_track_0_recording_artist-credit_name-credit_artist_name }}</td>
{% endif %}

{% if member.release_medium-list_medium_track-list_track_0_recording_title %}
    <td>{{ member.release_medium-list_medium_track-list_track_0_recording_title }}</td>
{% endif %}
 </tr>

  <tr>
{% if member.release_medium-list_medium_track-list_track_1_recording_artist-credit_name-credit_artist_name %}
    <td>{{ member.release_medium-list_medium_track-list_track_1_recording_artist-credit_name-credit_artist_name }}</td>
{% endif %}

{% if member.release_medium-list_medium_track-list_track_1_recording_title %}
    <td>{{ member.release_medium-list_medium_track-list_track_1_recording_title }}</td>
{% endif %}
 </tr>
  <tr>
{% if member.release_medium-list_medium_track-list_track_2_recording_artist-credit_name-credit_artist_name %}
    <td>{{ member.release_medium-list_medium_track-list_track_2_recording_artist-credit_name-credit_artist_name }}</td>
{% endif %}

{% if member.release_medium-list_medium_track-list_track_2_recording_title %}
    <td>{{ member.release_medium-list_medium_track-list_track_2_recording_title }}</td>
{% endif %}
 </tr>
```

Now, clearly, this is not the best way to do it. What I'm after is something that:

1. Looks for the relevant data
2. If the data is there, creates the cells and fills them out.

I'm pretty sure this can be done with Liquid, but I have no idea how. Can someone here help?

**EDIT:** Turns out I forgot the CSV file -- [here it is](http://pastebin.com/j5Uw5tug), on Pastebin.

**EDIT 2:** [This Cheat Sheet](http://cheat.markdunkley.com/) might be of help!

Comment: Possibly useful/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206869/iterate-over-hashes-in-liquid-templates

Comment: An example of the CSV file you are trying to process would help. Personally I think you will have much more success if you can convert to a JSON file and do some pre-processing to clean up the data.

Comment: Also, I don't think cleaning up the file is good as I will probably be merging it with another file (or several other files) from Musicbrainz later. Why would it be better to work with a JSON file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format of a CSV file inherently does not support repeated sections so I think it would be a bad fit for the variable length data format you are trying to use. I feel JSON is more appropriate for this use case as it can handle the structure of the source data you are trying to work with.

As a quick example I put the XML file you supplied through [this converter](http://codebeautify.org/xmltojson) to create a JSON version of the output. This was saved as "_data/music.json".

This liquid code was then used to parse this:

```
{% for item in site.data.music %}

    <h2> {{ item[1].release.title }}</h2>

    {% for medium in item[1].release.medium-list %}

    <h3> {{ medium[1].format }} </h3>

    <table border="1" style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td>Artist</td>
            <td>Track title</td>
        </tr>
        {% for track in medium[1].track-list.track %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ track.recording.artist-credit.name-credit.artist.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ track.recording.title }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This produces HTML like this (trimmed):

```
<h2> The Quatermass Film Music Collection</h2>    
<h3> CD </h3>
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Artist</td>
        <td>Track title</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tristram Cary</td>
        <td>Quatermass and the Pit: Opening Credits</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>Tristram Cary</td>
        <td>Quatermass and the Pit: Bones</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Based on this you should be able to produce the format you ultimately want.

Comment: Thanks so much, that's definitely something I can work from! One small thing to note: the indentation in your sample  Liquid code works as escaping, other than that it is great!

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to iterate over a csv file.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
      {% for column in include.datafile[0] %} 
        <th>{{ column[0] }}</th>
      {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for spec in include.datafile %} 
      <tr>
      {% for value in spec %}
        <td>{{ value[1] }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```