# What is the equivalent for this code in Liquid template?

Tags: ruby, liquid

I have an array of hashes:

```
a = [{a:"ahmed", b: "gaber"}, {a: "biga", b: "gaber"}]
```

I want to map the array into a comma separated string with each separated part being the concatenation of the values of a hash.
In ruby, this would be written:

```
a.map {|o| o[:a] + o[:b] }.join(",")
```

How can I write this in Liquid?

Comment: You can format code with 4 leading spaces. Can you check what you posted? I have the impression there is some cut+paste waste from another post (the part with up vote...)

Comment: I copied it from old question I wrote it then deleted, sorry I didn't note that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're writing directly to the output, you could use a `for` tag, e.g.:

```
{% for item in items %}{% if forloop.first == false %},{% endif %}{{ item.a }} {{ item.b }}{% endfor %}

==> "ahmed gaber,biga gaber"
```

But if you're trying to `assign` to a variable, I don't think there's a way to do that purely in liquid because there's no filter that is the equivalent to the ruby `map` function.  The closest I can think of is to preprocess the list so it looks like this:

```
a = [{a:"ahmed", b: "gaber", c: "ahmed gaber"}, 
     {a: "biga", b: "gaber", c: "biga gaber"}]
```

and then use liquid `map` to pluck the "c" field from each hash:

```
{{ assign csv = items | map: "c" | join: ","}}
The result is: {{ csv }}

==> "ahmed gaber,biga gaber"
```

Answer (score 1):

Liquid has a map filter for arrays, but it only lets you access one attribute from each object in your array:
https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/array-filters#map

There is a pretty thorough answer on iterating through hashes in Liquid here:
[Iterate over hashes in liquid templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206869/iterate-over-hashes-in-liquid-templates)

Using the above answer as a template, you could iterate (and present) your data in the way you specified with these tags:

```
{% for name in a %}
    {{ name.a }} {{ name.b }}{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```

One other piece to this markup is the use of the `forloop` variable from inside the loop. With this we can place a comma unless we're at the last entry in the array.

More on liquid forloops (and pretty much everything else liquid) here: https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers