# Check if variable is type of string or array in liquid

Tags: html, arrays, yaml, jekyll, liquid

In Jekyll you can use [liquid template](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/) and I am trying to write a nav that includes all links in the website.

```
sitemap:
  home: "/"
  demo:
    right: "/right"
    left: "/left"
```

What I am trying to achieve is to create a sidebar that icludes all those links. But certains links are under a section. The output should be the following

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/">home</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li>demo</li>
    <li>
      <a href="/right">right</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/left">left</a>
    </li
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Not all sections must have a title. The home link is a standalone link.
The demo links are all in the demo section.

In liquid I can loop through the sitemap in this way:

```
{% for nav in site.sitemap %}
<ul>
  <li>{{ nav[0] }}</li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

In this way, liquid will print `home` and `demo`.

What I need is to check if the **value** is a string or an array in order to print the array or a single link!

**Is there a way to check if the liquid variable is a string or an array?**
I can't find it in the documentation i linked before!

Answer (score 32):

> Is there a way to check if the liquid variable is a string or an array?

## Short answer: Yes

To check if a liquid variable is a string or a list of elements (array or hash), check if it has a first descendant, using the array filter [first](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/array-filters#first): `{% var.first %}` as follow :

```
{% if var.first %}
  // var is not a string
{% else %}
 // var is a string
{% endif %}
```

## Explanation:

the filter `first` return the first element of an array or a hash if it has one, if the variable is empty or not a list of element it return nothing, and since `nil` is a [`falsy value`](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/basics/true-and-false#falsy) in liquid, it works the same as `false` in the `if condition` above.

e.g :

```
# var1 = "a"     // string
{% var1.first %} // return:   // nil -> falsy

# var2 = [a,b,c] // array
{% var2.first %} // return: a

# var3 = {k1: a, k2: b, k3: c} // hash
{% var1.first %} // return: k1a

# var4 = {k1, k2, k3: c} // hash, first element is a key without associated value
{% var1.first %} // return: k1
```

## Solution to the OP issue: loop through the sitemap

Now that we can determine if an element is a string or not, we can do that:

```
{% for nav in site.sitemap %}
<ul>
  <li>
     {{ nav[0] }} :
        {% if nav[1].first %}
        // loop through: nav[1]
        {% else %}
          {{ nav[1] }}
        {% endif %}        
  </li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

but I found that's more convenient* to work the `sitemap` as list of elements **(a)**, instead a single big hash (as it is actually) **(b)** (cf. [YAML syntax](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/YAMLSyntax.html))

### 1. Edit the sitemap data structure

so I modified it's structure, by adding a `"- "` (a dash and a space) before each element:

```
  - home: "/"
  - demo:
    - right: "/right"
    - left: "/left"
```

which give us **a**:

```
{"home"=>"/"}{"demo"=>[{"right"=>"/right"}, {"left"=>"/left"}]}
```

instead of **b**:

```
{"home"=>"/", "demo"=>{"right"=>"/right", "left"=>"/left"}}
```

**Side Note**: you can put the sitemap in it's own file in: `_data/sitmap.yml` and access it by `site.data.sitemap`, in lieu of defined it as an attribute in the `_config.yml`, to keep it cleaner, thereby it'll look exactly as the above.

### 2. Create a sitemap template

since we'll going to include the `sitemap` in itself recursively (for each node with children ) we'll put this template in `_includes` folder and not `_layouts`

Notice also that Jekyll allows [passing parameters to includes](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/#passing-parameters-to-includes). But there is a catch, the `param` should be a `string` not an array, or hash. So, we have to make a string out of the links array.

here we go:

```
<ul>
  <!--                  links is a param -->
  {%for link in include.links %}

    <li>

      {% for part in link %}
        {{part[0]}} : <!-- part[0] : link name  -->

        {% if part[1].first %} <!-- the element has children -->

          <!-- concatenate jekyll array into a string -->
          {% assign _links = "" | split: "" %}
          {% for _link in part[1] %}
            {% assign _links = _links | push: _link %}
          {% endfor %}
          <!-- pass the string as a param to sitemap, then do the recursive dance -->
          {% include sitemap.html links = _links %}

        {% else %} <!-- no children -->

          {{part[1]}} <!-- part[1] : link url -->

        {% endif %}

      {% endfor%}

    </li>

  {%endfor%}

</ul>
```

### 3. Use the template :)

```html
<!-- include and init the param with this ↓, or `site.sitemap` if it's defined in `_config.yml`, or ...  -->
{% include sitemap.html links= site.data.sitemap %}
```

### 4. Output

for: `/_data/sitemap.yml`:

```ruby
- home : "/"
- about: "/about"
- archive:
  - left : "/left"
  - right: "/right"
  - other:
    - up: '/other/up'
    - down: '/other/down'
```

the template produce:

- home : /
- about : /about
- archive :

  - left : /left
  - right : /right
  - other :

    - up : /other/up
    - down : /other/down

so you have to put `part[0]` and `part[1]` of each link in an `<a> tag` like:

```html
<a href="{{part[1]}}"> {{part[0]}} </a>
```

Comment: \* why I think that using a list of object per link is more convenient than a single object/hash representing the sitemap ?

 1- the former option give more control, add specific attribute (e.g: icon, isHiden, ..) to some links but keep the whole structure relatively consistent.
 2- easier to concatenate, manipulate with all the liquid/jekyll [Array filters](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/array-filters)

Comment: Get key and value from liquid hash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206869

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Jekyll 2.8.5 and

```
var[0]
```

is falsy for string values, but truthy for an array (whose first element is truthy).

(On the other hand `var.first`, as recommended by the previously accepted answer, now returns the first character of the string, and so it doesn't seem to be a good way to determine if a value is an array anymore.)

Comment: I can confirm this works and the old answer is obsolete

Comment: Confirm it works, but I expect this 'bug' to be fixed some time and like .first, to return the first character of the text.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your structure as follows:

```
sitemap:
    home:
        link: "/"
    demo:
        children:
            right:
                link: "/right"
            left:
                link: "/left"
```

Now all your objects follow the same pattern: instead of testing types, you can just test if an object exists. You can also use [recursion by inclusion](http://build.pixelunion.net/shopify-liquid-tip-recursion-by-inclusion/) to parse the sitemap:

```
{% for nav in site.sitemap %}
<ul>
    {% include 'print-li' %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

With 'print-li':

```
<li>
{% if nav.link %}
    <a href="{{ nav.link }}">{{ nav[0] }}</a>
{% else %}
    {{ nav[0] }}
{% endif %}

{% if nav.children %}
    {% for nav in nav.children %}
        {% include 'print-li' %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</li>
```