# Jekyll / liquid for loop being mysterious

Tags: loops, jekyll, liquid

I am trying to use the for loop in Jekyll to render sample data. I can reference the markdown objects or whatever they are called directly, but when I use a for loop it doesn’t work. Here’s an example of the problem I am having:

markdown file with data:

```
tests:  
  test1:  
    number: 1 . 
  test2:  
    number: 2 . 
  test3:  
    number: 3 .
```

sessions.html:

```
<p>{{ page.tests.test1.number }}</p>
<p>{{ page.tests.test2.number }}</p>
<p>{{ page.tests.test3.number }}</p>
```

This outputs to:

```
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
```

If I do this instead:

```
{% for test in page.tests %}
  <p>{{ test.number }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I get:

```
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

I can even do this:

```
{% for test in page.tests %}
  <p>{{ test }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

And get:

```
<p>test1{"number"=>1}</p>
<p>test2{"number"=>2}</p>
<p>test3{"number"=>3}</p>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
{% for test in page.tests %}
  <p>{{ test.number }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

You are iterating over `page.tests`. Since `page.tests` is a hash and not a list, you are iterating over the **key-value pairs** of that object. (See [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206869/iterate-over-hashes-in-liquid-templates)).

The **keys** are `test1`, `test2` and `test3`, you can access them with `test[0]`.

But you need the **value**, in this case you can use `test[1]`, and to get the number, you can call `test[1].number`:

```
{% for test in page.tests %}
  <p>{{ test[1].number }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

And you will get the same output as in your first example.

Or, instead of `test1`, `test2` and `test3`, you may try to define a **list:**

```
tests:
  - number: 1
  - number: 2
  - number: 3
```

This way, your code will work too:

```
{% for test in page.tests %}
  <p>{{ test.number }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```